# jQuery date picker - Disable dates after the selection from the first date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Date 1: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
    <p>Date 2: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

There are two date pickers in my code here. What I want is to disable dates when I select a date from the first date picker. That is suppose if I select date like `15/01/2015` from the first date picker. Now in the second date picker all the dates after `15/01/2015` will be disabled. But the dates before `15/01/2015` will be enabled in the second date picker.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the maxDate option

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker().change(function () {
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
    });
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/09L69cfz/)

Answer (score 0):

[`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event fires when you select a date from DatePicker.

Try the following code.

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date) {
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
                'maxDate': date
                //'minDate' : date
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You can manipulate the dates using [*maxDate*](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) and [*minDate*](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) properties.